# How to add text as page variable to node add form? Or in other works print explanation/guideline text

Tags: theming, nodes, forms

I want to include my content type's explanation/submission guideline text on node add form/page.

I need to insert it into header element and therefore a variable would be suitable.

I would assume it should already be available on page--node--add--special-content-type.tpl.php but I think it isn't.

Also, this text is automatically appended on the end of the page which is silly and why I wan't to change it.

And to mention following doesn't print it:

```
  <?php print render($page['help']); ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The core [**page.tpl.php**](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!page.tpl.php/7.x) template doesn't know anything about any current node object or help information from its node type. The snippet you're using is for printing a region named `help`, not a node type's help test.

That help information is retrieved by the System help block and is placed in whatever theme region you've configured in the block admin UI (**/admin/structure/block**). You're better off utilizing that block with your theme regions rather inserting a variable into your page template.

However, if you're really wanting to push this information into your template you can evoke [`node_help()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_help/7.x) to retrieve the information for your template variable and push in your template.php's `template_preprocess_page()` function:

```
/**
 * Override or insert variables into the page template.
 */
function MYTHEME_process_page(&$vars) {
  // $help_text will be available as printable markup with page.tpl.php
  $vars['help_text'] = node_help(current_path(), arg());
}
```

Comment: Well, you answered two question at once :) And both were very well to the point. Thank you!